# pick nearest value in dataframe pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, difference

I have a dataframe and need to pick nearest value if there is Nan.(from open or price_orderbook column) whichever is nearer.

```
time                open    high    low     close   timestamp    price_orderbook
                        
2022-02-22 19:05:10 2.128   2.129   2.128   2.129   NaN              NaN
2022-02-22 19:05:11 NaN      NaN    NaN       NaN   NaN              NaN
2022-02-22 19:05:12 NaN      NaN    NaN       NaN   NaN              NaN
2022-02-22 19:05:13 NaN      NaN    NaN       NaN   NaN              NaN
2022-02-22 19:05:14 NaN      NaN    NaN       NaN   NaN              NaN
2022-02-22 19:05:15 2.129   2.129   2.129   2.129   NaN              NaN
2022-02-22 19:05:16 2.128   2.128   2.128   2.128   NaN              NaN
2022-02-22 19:05:17 NaN      NaN    NaN       NaN   NaN              NaN
2022-02-22 19:05:18 2.128   2.128   2.128   2.128   1.645557e+09    2.1285
2022-02-22 19:05:19 NaN      NaN    NaN       NaN   NaN              NaN
2022-02-22 19:05:20 NaN      NaN    NaN       NaN   NaN              NaN
2022-02-22 19:05:21 NaN      NaN    NaN       NaN   1.645557e+09    2.1285
2022-02-22 19:05:22 NaN      NaN    NaN       NaN   NaN              NaN
2022-02-22 19:05:23 NaN      NaN    NaN       NaN   NaN              NaN
```

Example:

```
df['closer']= "value" if there is open or price_orderbook else search for nearest open or price_orderbook
```

Is there anything in pandas that helps me out.

Comment: Can you add expected ouput to question? WHat values should be in column `closer` ?

Comment: By nearest, do you mean one in the nearest cell, or the nearest value numerically?

Comment: the values which are nearer to the time, either open or price_orderbook values.. @jezrael

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem Nearest cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace mising values from `open` by non missing values if exist in `price_orderbook` first, then remove all another missing values by [`Series.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dropna.html) and for nearest values use [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) with `method='nearest'`:

```
df['closer'] = (df['open'].fillna(df['price_orderbook'])
                          .dropna()
                          .reindex(df.index, method='nearest'))
```

---

```
print (df)
                      open   high    low  close     timestamp  \
2022-02-22 19:05:10  2.128  2.129  2.128  2.129           NaN   
2022-02-22 19:05:11    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN           NaN   
2022-02-22 19:05:12    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN           NaN   
2022-02-22 19:05:13    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN           NaN   
2022-02-22 19:05:14    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN           NaN   
2022-02-22 19:05:15  2.129  2.129  2.129  2.129           NaN   
2022-02-22 19:05:16  2.128  2.128  2.128  2.128           NaN   
2022-02-22 19:05:17    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN           NaN   
2022-02-22 19:05:18  2.128  2.128  2.128  2.128  1.645557e+09   
2022-02-22 19:05:19    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN           NaN   
2022-02-22 19:05:20    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN           NaN   
2022-02-22 19:05:21    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN  1.645557e+09   
2022-02-22 19:05:22    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN           NaN   
2022-02-22 19:05:23    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN           NaN   

                     price_orderbook  closer  
2022-02-22 19:05:10              NaN  2.1280  
2022-02-22 19:05:11              NaN  2.1280  
2022-02-22 19:05:12              NaN  2.1280  
2022-02-22 19:05:13              NaN  2.1290  
2022-02-22 19:05:14              NaN  2.1290  
2022-02-22 19:05:15              NaN  2.1290  
2022-02-22 19:05:16              NaN  2.1280  
2022-02-22 19:05:17              NaN  2.1280  
2022-02-22 19:05:18           2.1285  2.1280  
2022-02-22 19:05:19              NaN  2.1280  
2022-02-22 19:05:20              NaN  2.1285  
2022-02-22 19:05:21           2.1285  2.1285  
2022-02-22 19:05:22              NaN  2.1285  
2022-02-22 19:05:23              NaN  2.1285
```

Comment: if i want to do some math over open, how do i add that over here in same line mentioned or do i need to create new column for easier use..

Comment: @Kowsi - then use `open = df['open'] + 100 / 52` (some maths, change like need) and then `df['closer'] = (open.fillna(df['price_orderbook']).dropna().reindex(df.index, method='nearest'))`